# How to prevent touch event if swipe occurs in Android?

Tags: android, swipe, gesture

After adding touch events, my swipe events are not triggered. How can I prevent touch event to happen if swipe occurs? Here is my code:

```
    favorites.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getApplicationContext()) {
        public void onSwipeTop() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeRight() {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeBottom() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onTouch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like OnSwipeTouchListener is your defined class which implements onTouchListner. And you override onTouch() method.

All the touch event happened on the favorites view will be handled by this listner through onTouch()  method. The key is you return true in this method, so no following callback method will be invoked anymore.

By the way, touch event handling is complicated. I am curious where is the touch event detection code.